# Parse.com crash with basic project on iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform, crash

I've been using Parse for the last few weeks and I've really been enjoying it - today I decided to try my app on an iOS 7.0 device and unfortunately I'm getting a crash, immediately.

I narrowed down the crash to Parse and created a single view project, with a single library - parse. In the app delegate I call the following two lines:

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse setApplicationId:appID
              clientKey:appSecret];
```

This results in a EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, and the app crashes immediately (black screen on device). The app runs fine in the 7.1 simulator. I've got no problem dropping 7.0, but Parse say they support down to iOS 6.0 - any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of crash]

edit - I also can't test using a 7.0 sim as I'm on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue I was having was directly related to using Parse from Cocoapods. Perhaps some libraries aren't being included correctly?

If I follow the quick start guide for an existing project without using Cocoapods, the app runs fine on iOS7.0.